# MySQL OR question

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can use the `OR` or something similar inside a join, inside the mysql code below.

```
INNER JOIN users_friends ON users.user_id = users_friends.friend_id OR users_friends.user_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN users_friends
    ON users.user_id IN (users_friends.friend_id, users_friends.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
INNER JOIN users_friends ON (users.user_id = users_friends.friend_id OR users_friends.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean...

```
INNER JOIN users_friends ON (users.user_id = users_friends.friend_id OR
                             users.user_id = users_friends.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Used Many types of this query
INNER JOIN users_friends as U ON (users.user_id = U.friend_id OR U.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN users_friends ON (users.user_id = users_friends.friend_id ||
                             users.user_id = users_friends.user_id)